# WPF application fail to update the rectangle around the mouse pointer on click

Tags: wpf, mouse, invalidation

Is it just me?

I’m a WPF newbie. Everything is nice and shining, and I managed to write a small application that meets my needs, but I noticed that many times, for instance when I click a button or a list view, the event is handled (e.g. list view selection is changed), but the area under the mouse is not updated, so a small rectangle at the place where the mouse pointer was is not updated – e.g. the background color of the entire GridView selected item line is turned to dark blue, but there is a white rectangle area where the mouse was.

I couldn’t find any reference to this behavior on the web and was wondering if it is just me – something in my environment or in my code? And more importantly, is there a way to fix it?

PS
I usually run the application from Debug from VS 2008, but this also happens when I run the release build outside of the IDE.

Thanks,
splintor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds most likely to be a video driver issue -- it's certainly not expected behaviour, and it's not something you could do accidentally in your code.  So it may depend on your graphics card, installed drivers and operating system.  One possible way to diagnose it is to try tweaking the rendering settings, particularly the hardware acceleration option.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx, especially DisableHWAcceleration key and (for testing purposes only!) UseReferenceRasterizer.

Comment: Indeed, setting DisableHWAcceleration to 1 made the problem go away, so there's probably a problem with my laptop's Windows XP Video Driver. Thanks a million. I'll leave DisableHWAcceleration as 1 for now, but do you have any idea how I can troubleshoot it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, splintor, can't help you on troubleshooting.  I guess check with the laptop or card manufacturer for updated drivers, any DirectX patches, etc., and if that still doesn't help then report the issue on the manufacturer's support forums.